# I want to add Table information to Form information, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

The structure is ideal when checked in JS, but when viewed on the PHP send side, the structure has collapsed. What mistakes are there?

```
// テーブル部
$('#form').submit(function() {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', "hidden");
    input.setAttribute('name', "CallerIdsList[][]");

    let array_big = [];
    $(".callernum-row").each(function(_index, _element) {
        let array_small = [];
        let id = $(this).find(".callernum-id").text();
        let num = $(this).find(".callernum-num").text();
        let name = $(this).find(".callernum-name").text();
        let prefix = $(this).find(".callernum-prefix").text();

        array_small.push(id);
        array_small.push(num);
        array_small.push(name);
        array_small.push(prefix);
        array_big.push(array_small);
    });

    input.setAttribute('value', array_big);
    this.appendChild(input);

    return true;
});
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@foreach($response["CallerIdsList"] as $CallerId)
<tr class="callernum-row">
    <td>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="checkbox{{ $loop->index }}">
            <label for="checkbox{{ $loop->index }}"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="callernum-id" style="display: none;">{{ $CallerId["CallerNumId"] }}</td>
    <td class="callernum-num">{{ $CallerId["CallerNum"] }}</td>
    <td class="callernum-name">{{ $CallerId["CallerNumName"] }}</td>
    <td class="callernum-prefix">{{ $CallerId["PrefixNum"] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

JS :

[image]

PHP :

[image]

：Do you need any other information to resolve this?

Comment: `input.setAttribute('value', array_big);` will store the toString of the array. You could JSON.stringify it and json_parse it on the server

Comment: @mplungjan
Do I need to put them in each js and php location? I'm a newbie so I've never experienced this but I'm up for the challenge. Thank you very much.

Comment: as @mplungjan suggested, you are pushing an array in the value attribute of an html element .. that of course will be converted to string in a bad way. First of all it would be more common to use the `.value` property instead of setting it as an attribute of the element.. but if you want to see the value back as an array in php, since you are using the `<input name="something[i]">` (square parenthesis) strategy, maybe you have to stick with adding several inputs (like:  CallerIdsList[a][b]) => $_POST['a']['b'];)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct way to write it, but I was able to solve the problem by adding the input directly without writing it in the JS.

There are so many things I didn't know and couldn't understand anything. I will come back with more knowledge. Thank you for your advice.

```
</td>
<-- ▼ add ▼ -->
<input type="hidden" name="CallerIdsList[{{ $loop->index }}][]" value="{{ $CallerId['CallerNumId'] }}">
<input type="hidden" name="CallerIdsList[{{ $loop->index }}][]" value="{{ $CallerId['CallerNum'] }}">
<input type="hidden" name="CallerIdsList[{{ $loop->index }}][]" value="{{ $CallerId['CallerNumName'] }}">
<input type="hidden" name="CallerIdsList[{{ $loop->index }}][]" value="{{ $CallerId['PrefixNum'] }}">
<-- ▲ add ▲ -->
<td class="callernum-id" style="display: none;">{{ $CallerId["CallerNumId"] }}</td>
```